# composer require could find package

Tags: laravel, composer-php

I am trying to install [unideveloper/laravel-password](https://github.com/unicodeveloper/laravel-password) in my laravel 5.8 project using:

```
composer require --dev "unicodeveloper/laravel-password": "1.0.*"
```

But, I get the following error:

> [InvalidArgumentException]
>   Could not find package 1.0.*.
>
> Did you mean one of these?
>
> lastguest/ev
>
> 1032443065/pudge
>
> appium/php-client
>
> authbucket/oauth2
>
> wicochandra/captcha

how to solve this please?

Answer (score 2):

That syntax is for `composer.json` file and is not correct for CLI command

```
composer require vendor/package:version
```

for example:

```
composer require --dev unicodeveloper/laravel-password:1.0.*
```

Hope this helps

Comment: You should use a version range, not an explicit version number, in your second example.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of updating it into composer.json file ,
Install it directly using the following command .

```
composer require unicodeveloper/laravel-password
```

Which is worked for me . 
If you are looking for particular version , 
Then you can install the particular version  by using the command :

```
composer require unicodeveloper/laravel-password:1.0.*
```